# How to convert multiple json objects interpreted as string into Json dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have my data as below which looks like multiple json dictionaries but it is of type string. Can someone please help me out to convert it into json dictionary ?

```
{"id": "1305857561179152385", "tweet": "If you like vintage coke machines and guys who look like Fred Flintstone you'll love the short we've riffed: Coke R\u2026 ", "ts": "Tue Sep 15 13:14:38 +0000 2020"}{"id": "1305858267067883521", "tweet": "Chinese unicorn Genki Forest plots own beverage hits  #China #Chinese #Brands #GoingGlobal\u2026 ", "ts": "Tue Sep 15 13:17:27 +0000 2020"}{"id": "1305858731293507585", "tweet": "RT @CinemaCheezy: If you like vintage coke machines and guys who look like Fred Flintstone you'll love the short we've riffed: Coke Refresh\u2026", "ts": "Tue Sep 15 13:19:17 +0000 2020"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
let = "{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}{'e':'f', 'g':'h'}"
let_list = let.split('}')
d = []
for i in let_list[:-1]:
    val = eval(i + '}')
    d.append(val)
```

The output will be two dictionaries

```
print(d)
# Will print as shown
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, {'e':'f', 'g':'h'}]
```

Comment: <class 'list'> 
This the type i get after the code. How do i convert it to type <class 'dict'> ?

Comment: {'test': {'id': '1305858731293507585', 'tweet': "RT @CinemaCheezy: If you like vintage coke machines and guys who look like Fred Flintstone you'll love the short we've riffed: Coke Refresh…", 'ts': 'Tue Sep 15 13:19:17 +0000 2020'}}

Comment: It gives me just 1 dictionary not all... how do i get all the dictionaries ?

Comment: If you iterate over the list, which is `d` here, you will get all the dictionaries. Its list of dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

json.loads(json_str)
```

Comment: [ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 228 (char 227)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 36, in lambda_handler
    jsonFile = json.loads(jsonremovebrace2)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)END RequestId: a00d25f0-112b-4f53-ab94-3e1cea72a23b